# Running VNCserver on docker container

Tags: docker

I'm quite new to docker. I have a container running and I wanted to VNC into the container. (open the port) I'm not sure how to do it.

My container is running inside a VM.

```
#Docker ps

fc86020fff36        centos:6.6          "/bin/bash"         3 days ago          Up 3 days                                   drunk_tesla
```

This is the netstat result.

```
[root@fc86020fff36 bin]# netstat -anp | grep vnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5902                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7914/Xvnc           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6549/Xvnc
```

I'm really confused, any help would be great.

Comment: could you edit your question with the command used to run the docker container?

Comment: I dont think its command since I need to open up the port and also run vncserver on docker (which I am now).. expose it to outside

Comment: Did you expose those ports? using docker run -p 7914:7914 -p 6549:6549 because I can't see them in your `docker ps`